# Layers from SQL Server not loading in geoserver

Tags: geoserver

I've loaded a shapefile into SQL Server using ogr2ogr and I can connect to the database/layer and create a store and publish the layer, however when i try to preview the layer with the openlayers option it returns this which suggests a problem with the SRS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.1.1/WMS_exception_1_1_1.dtd">       <ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1" >   <ServiceException>
  java.io.IOException: No such resource: generic.sld
No such resource: generic.sld
</ServiceException></ServiceExceptionReport>
```

Following the answer here: [Geoserver - Connect to a SQL Server 2008 Express and fetch data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853918/geoserver-connect-to-a-sql-server-2008-express-and-fetch-data)
I have updated the geometry in SQL using:

```
update xxx set ogr_geometry =  geometry::STGeomFromText(ogr_geometry.STAsText(), 27700)
```

and reloaded the layer

...but I get the same error. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that GeoServer is unable to determine what sort of geometry is in your table and is attempting to use the generic style to display them, but for some reason `generic.sld` is missing from your styles (possibly an upgrade issue?). The solution is to go to the layer `publishing` tab and change the default style to one of `point`, `line` or `polygon` depending on the geometry type of your table. Or you can [create](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/) and apply a style of your own.

Comment: Excellent answer!